# Rasperry Pi4 does not show the Hostname

Tags: linux, cmd, raspberry-pi, hostname, raspberry-pi4

I´m using Raspberry Pi 4 and Windows 10 machine 
And I setup a custom hostname in the raspberry by $ sudo raspi-config
and then when I use hostname in the raspberry it is given me the new hostname.
But I´m traying to get this hostname from my Windows machine and it is not give my.

```
pi@PLC:~ $ hostname -I
169.254.100.158 192.168.1.72 fd18:5644:3369:d200:f282:15d1:9085:858

pi@PLC:~ $ hostname

PLC
```

When I ping my raspberry or nmap or arp -a does not given me any Host-name response any suggestion. 
For example when I ping to 8.8.8.8 C:\Users\n-orb>ping -a 8.8.8.8 it is given me the Hostname but if I ping the Raspberry it is not given me the hostname.

```
C:\Users\n-orb>ping -a 8.8.8.8
ping to dns.google [8.8.8.8] with 32 bytes 

C:\Users\n-orb>ping -a 168.254.100.158
ping to 168.254.100.158 with 32 bytes

C:\Users\n-orb>ping 192.168.1.72
ping to 192.168.1.72 with 32 bytes
```

Does anyone know how to get the hostname.?

Comment: (1) have you rebooted the Pi since making the change? (2) have you checked `/etc/HOSTNAME` to see if it holds the new hostname? (3) have you checked the `/etc/hosts` file to see that there is an entry with `127.0.0.1` that uses the new hostname as an alias along with `localhost`?, (4) on the Pi have you issued `hostname` and `hostname -f` to ensure local name resolution is working correctly? Start there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolving an IP address to a hostname is done via *Reverse DNS Lookup*. Reverse DNS Lookup is actually nothing special, it's just normal DNS Lookup in the "magic" sub-domain `in-addr.arpa.`

When you try to resolve the IP address `192.168.1.72` to a hostname, what is *actually* happening, is that the DNS resolver is trying to resolve the `PTR` record for the hostname `71.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.`

So, when you want your IP address `192.168.1.72` to resolve to the hostname `PLC`, you need to configure your DNS server so that it responds to a `PTR` query for `71.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.` with the response `PLC` in exactly the same way that, for the other direction, you set up your DNS server so that it responds to an `A` query for `PLC` with the response `192.168.1.72`.